# How to install packages as subdirectory of metapackage?

Tags: ros, catkin, stack, metapackage, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, currently I have packages that install their binaries to catkin_ws/install/lib/package_name

I made a metapackage to contain these directories. Now I would like them to install like this: install/lib/meta_package_name/package_name

Is there any good way of achieving this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193972/how-to-install-packages-as-subdirectory-of-metapackage?/) by [pachuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20216/pachuc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unless I misunderstand you, metapackages don't work that way (they are not stacks). They are essentially a way to group a number of packages and make them easily installable by only installing the metapackage. Dependency resolution then pulls in the others.

In the original design, metapackages didn't even have a `CMakeLists.txt`.

Do you have any specific reason for such a directory layout?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pachuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20216/pachuc/) on 2014-10-01**:
well my source is laid out like this: /src/group_of_files/many_individual_package_folders.

I was hoping that my install could look the same way ie: install/lib/group_of_files_/my_packages

I think this is mostly just for convenience and easily identifying package install locations.

**Comment by [pachuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20216/pachuc/) on 2014-10-01**:
i guess its not necessary, but it would be nice. So did stacks used to work this way (sorry im new to catkin/ros)? If so, why did they change it for metapackages? I guess the only point of a metapackage is just to install easier?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-01**:
If you really want to know, take a look at the rationale behind the move to catkin (FHS compliance, etc). Stacks did not put everything in `install/lib`, but they did contain all packages.

As to 'being nice': you typically do things like `$(find PKGNAME)`, so does it matter where things are?

**Comment by [pachuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20216/pachuc/) on 2014-10-01**:
ok, thanks for the answer. I guess it doesn't really matter... its just... annoying lol